# FlagsAttribute Enum problems

Tags: c#, .net, enum-flags

So I'm building an MSNP (windows live messenger) client. And I've got this list of capabilities

```
public enum UserCapabilities : long
{
    None = 0,
    MobileOnline = 1 << 0,
    MSN8User = 1 << 1,
    RendersGif = 1 << 2,
    ....
    MsgrVersion7 = 1 << 30,
    MsgrVersion8 = 1 << 31,
    MsgrVersion9 = 1 << 32,
}
```

full list here http://paste.pocoo.org/show/383240/

The server sends each users capabilities to the client as a long integer, which I take and cast it to UserCapabilities

```
capabilities = Int64.Parse(e.Command.Args[3]);
user._capabilities = (UserCapabilities)capabilities;
```

This is fine, and with atleast one user (with a capability value of 1879474220), I can do

```
Debug.WriteLine(_msgr.GetUser(usr).Capabilities);
```

and this will output

```
RendersGif, RendersIsf, SupportsChunking, IsBot, SupportsSChannel, SupportsSipInvite, MsgrVersion5, MsgrVersion6, MsgrVersion7
```

But with another user, who has the capability value of (3055849760), when I do the same, I just get the same number outputted

```
3055849760
```

What I would like to be seeing is a list of capabilities, as it is with the other user.

I'm sure there is a very valid reason for this happening, but no matter how hard I try to phrase the question to Google, I am not finding an answer.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The definition of the shift operators means that only the 5 least significant bits are used for 32-bit numbers and only the first 6 bits for 64-bit; meaning:

```
1 << 5
```

is ***identical*** to

```
1 << 37
```

(both are `32`)

By making it:

```
MsgrVersion9 = 1L << 32
```

you make it a 64-bit number, which is why @leppie's fix works; otherwise the `<<` is considered ***first*** (and note that `1<<32` ***is identical to*** `1<<0`, i.e. `1`), and ***then*** the resulting `1` is converted to a `long`; so it is still `1`.

From §14.8 in the ECMA spec:

> For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:
>
> - When the type of *x* is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of *count*. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F`.
> - When the type of *x* is `long` or `ulong`, the shift count is given by the low-order six bits of *count*. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x3F`.
>
> If the resulting shift count is zero, the shift operators simply return the value of x.
>
> Shift operations never cause overflows and produce the same results in checked and unchecked context

Comment: It might not be called 'overflow' but the effect is the same, ie `(1L << 33) & 0xffffffff`. I think the spec text implies that an overflow exception will never be thrown when shifting.

Comment: @leppie - but if it was just the avoidance of overflow, then you should expect that (for `int`) anything `<<32` would be zero; the same as shifting it `<<16` twice (which it isn't).

Answer (score 10):

The problem could be with arithmetic overflow.

Specifically at:

```
MsgrVersion8 = 1 << 31,
MsgrVersion9 = 1 << 32,
```

I suggest you make it:

```
MsgrVersion8 = 1L << 31,
MsgrVersion9 = 1L << 32,
```

To prevent accidental overflow.

**Update:**

Seems likely as the smaller number on 'touches' 31 bits, while the bigger one 'touches' 32 bits.

Comment: The reason is simple: 1 is `Int32` and 31 is also `Int32`, the result again is `Int32`, which is a signed int, which has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647, but 1 << 31 is 2,147,483,648, so it will overflow to -2,147,483,648.

Comment: @Daniel @NoPyGod this is nothing to do with overflow; see my answer